# Proper programming - should a function return a value on all code paths?

Tags: vb.net, return-value

My VB.Net class's constructor is passed a value for an `Enum` property.  If I create a method in this class that uses `Select Case` statements, is it proper programming to include a `Case Else` line (that would never be executed)?  I understand it, just want to know what is "proper" programming.

```
Public Enum eList
    one = 1
    two = 2
    three = 3
End Enum

Public Class Class1
    Private _eValue As eList

    Public Sub New(ByVal ePassed As eList)
        _eValue = ePassed
    End Sub

    Public Function SomeMethod() As Object
        Select Case _eValue
            '(all eList items accounted for below)
            Case eList.one
                'do something
            Case eList.two
                'do something else
            Case eList.three
                'do another thing
            Case Else
                '  should I put a Return <value> line here?
        End Select
        '  and should I also put a Return <value> line here?
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: if you pass value that is not in the Enum, you should almost certainly throw an exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific answer to your question is yes, all possible code paths for a function should return a value.  If every case in your select case returned a value and the else also returned a value, then all your paths are covered.  I think it is personal taste whether you should have the return in the Else case or at the end of the function.  Some developers prefer to only ever have a single return statement at the end of a function.

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule of thumb, yes, you should be sure that all execution paths return *something*, even if that *something* is `Nothing`.  I primarily say this because several programming languages won't even compile unless you comply to this, so you may as well get in the habit.

But with that said, in this specific case, we probably want to do some validation, and actually `Throw` an exception any time that our `_eValue` isn't being set to a valid value in the `Enum`.  That'd be good advise here, and good advise to apply here and other scenarios as well.

It's always important to be sure we validate our input.

In a lot of cases, having a single return can make our code more readable.  So, consider making your function look something like this:

```
Public Function SomeMethod() As Object
    Dim SomeReturnValue As Object = Nothing
    Select Case _eValue
        Case eList.one
            SomeReturnValue = New Something()
        Case eList.two
            SomeReturnValue = New SomethingElse()
        Case eList.three
            SomeReturnValue = New YetSomeOtherThing()
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("Invalid State Exception: _eValue property in an invalid state.")
    End Select
    Return SomeReturnValue
End Function
```